# Microsoft Access vs Native SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hypothetical: Let's say you are writing complex queries to a database and it is very important that the data you extracted is the correct result set (e.g., that you didn't mess up a JOIN by not using all the correct keys, and all the other things that can go wrong, et cetera).

What would you rather use to do this? Would you write the query using Microsoft Access and its Design View, or would you write it in native SQL using a SQL IDE? What is the better professional choice?

Edit: In other words, what kind of client environment do you use for producing SQL queries? An environment supporting native SQL programming, or one supporting a graphical design view like that of Microsoft Access or Crystal Reports?

Thanks in advance your feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Access Query Builder Thing will only write SQL in its own syntax (of which, BTW, it has two: ANSI-89 Query Mode syntax amd ANSI-92 Query Mode syntax) and not that of the target data source. For example, if SQL Server is your 'backend' and Access is your 'client' then Access cannot write TSQL SQL Server syntax.

Even when targeting the Access's own data engine, I find the Access Query Builder Thing hopeless. Even if you ignore the 'Design View' (which can only handle the most basic syntax) and type SQL directly into its 'SQL View' window, the system will often change it, introducing syntax errors in the process. If you really must use the Access Database Engine (ACE, Jet, whatever) then I recommend creating `VIEW`s and `PROCEDURE`s (and tables and their constraints, come to that) using SQL DDL.

Comment: Do you think a tool like Access is a safer and more reliable way of extracting important data than an IDE like SQLDeveloper, where you write native (raw) SQL code?

Comment: @ktm5124: I suppose the Access UI does shriek a warning at you when you are about to execute a SQL statement that will affect n rows, do you really want to continue, etc. Personally, it drove me mad and I couldn't find a way to switch it off. I've no problem writing raw code. If you think you might be taking a risk, begin a transaction and don't commit until you've check control totals, etc. Always have a backup, always test offline first, etc.

Comment: @onedaywhen--it's really easy to turn off those warnings (which I also hate). In 2007, it's Office button->Access Options->Advanced, then uncheck the "Confirm" options that you don't want to see. I think it was on Tools->Options in earlier versions.

Comment: Turning off those warnings actually means you can execute SQL that will result in inconsistent updates and you'll never know about it. There are good reasons for the way Access was designed, and going against that puts your data in peril if you don't know exactly what you're doing. That is, if you're going to use the Access UI to execute your SQL (rather than code), then you really need to let the Access UI provide you with all the information you'll need when you encounter error conditions.

Answer (score 5):

I personally started out using the Access query editor to make my queries but the most important thing was I started to look at the SQL it was generating. When the time came to make some new queries I wrote them in raw SQL and checked my results against the same query made using the query editor. I now write a lot in the SSMS IDE doing all the SQL coding “by hand”.

It’s the normal learning curve,

- start with the support
- Try with out support but check against it
- Write without support

Too many people just stick at step 1 which is ok but kind of stops your growth and as soon as the safety blanket of a visual designer goes away it can be quite a culture shock!

Comment: +1 that's how I learned SQL in fact. at some point you get to a level where you don't like things about the generated SQL but then the wizard has already brought you a long way

Answer (score 1):

If the DBMS in question is Microsoft SQL Server then use Management Studio. It has many, many more productivity features that you won't find in Access.

Answer (score 1):

To me, the answer to the question depends on where you're going to execute the SQL. If you're executing it in Access, then write it in Access. If you're executing it in SQL Server, write it in whichever tools make that easiest (and create SQL in SQL Server's dialect).

I dissent from the criticism of the Access query designer. I think it's insane to write your SQL by hand and risk mistakes, and then have it "tidied up" by Access, anyway. There are good reasons why Access processes your literal SQL -- it's to insure that it's in a form that the Jet/ACE query optimizer can evaluate properly in order to produce the most efficient execution plan. Why anyone would want to skip the benefits that come from that completely mystifies me.

I still use the query designer all the time, and I've been doing this for over 16 years. Sure, I often use it only to start my SQL, and then manipulate the results in code, but it's much easier to do that than to try to write complex JOINs or properly qualify everything by typing it all in.

I think the people who are hostile to it have an ego problem -- they are like the oldsters who say that back in my day we had to walk to school in bare feet and it was uphill both ways, and they liked it that way.

Personally, I'm glad for the shoes and for the ride on the bus, and will use both, unless they get in the way of a specific task.

Comment: I actually find that an "extra layer" like Access obfuscates the query. It's easier for me to figure out what's going on - what the query is trying to get at - by looking at a native, well-written query. At the same time, I feel a little guilty writing native SQL for important matters...

Comment: Also, I think it's simply faster to hand-code it. But then again, there is the guilt, haha - the reason for this thread...

Comment: @ktm5124 Ditto on the faster to hand code.  Then for complex queries you keep layering on or adding your subqueries and it gives a nice step progression where you can see the results from each step.

Answer (score 0):

Designing/Writing queries can be done in either of the tools. Main point is data storage. MS Access is not a real database engine. Try to do away with Access as a database.

As a professional I will always chose SQL Server over Access. If I don't have full blown SQL Server then I will try to live with "SQL Server 2008 Express with Advanced Services".

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with SQL Server. (Sounds more like a backend than a client? I'm interested in the clients people choose to employ, e.g. Access, Oracle SQL Developer, etc.) I should have made this clear.

Comment: SQL Server IS a client people choose to employ. Not many professionals will choose Access over SQL Server.

Comment: Sorry, @Nellius, that's just wrong. SS is *not* a client, by definition. SS *Management Studio* can be seen as a client, but SS itself is a *server*.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you don't understand-- SQL Server Management Studio has *BETTER* design capabilties than MS Access.

You just want Query-By-Design?

You can highlight *ANY* SQL Statement and right-click 'Design Query in Editor'